# Vmware 8.0 and ubuntu bionic- gcc not found

Tags: gcc, vmware, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install vmware 8 on kubuntu bionic with gcc-7.3.  The installation process went well until the message "gcc is not found".  gcc is there but I guess vmware 8 is too old and does not recognize gcc version 7.3.

I have tried to manually compiled the modules (vmmon and stuff) but an error came out.  An example is shown below.

```
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: At top level:
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:175:19: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
         .fault  = LinuxDriverFault
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:175:19: note: (near initialization for ‘vmuser_mops.fault’)
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘init_module’:
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:346:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘init_timers’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    init_timer(&linuxState.pollTimer);
    ^~~~~~~~~~
    init_timers
```

Is there a workaround?

Many thanks

Comment: gcc output says there was `-Werror` option which converts warning into fatal error. Try to delete `-Werror` flags from compilation or add `-Wno-error=type` where type is `incompatible-pointer-types` etc. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Many thanks.  Unfortunately there are several other error msgs.